# Can IBM DB2 return a 0 (zero) when no records are found?

Tags: sql, db2

for example :
I have a table with student ID and student grades

```
-----------------------
ID  |  grades
-----------------------
1   |  80
2   |  28
-----------------------
```

I want to get 0 when I query about ID = 3
can I do that ?

like select grades from student where id = 3 .
I want to get 0 because ID is not in the table

Comment: There is not enough information here.  What query do you run to get the data for student id 1?  Edit your question to include that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Run a select command with the reserved function called `count`:

```
select count(*) from STUDENT.GRADES where ID=3
```

It should be just like that.

Comment: While the result of `COUNT(*)` will indeed be `0`, the problem is that the statement will return no rows.  So, really, he gets no answer back at all, much less a zero.  Also, one presumes he needs the grade back normally, not a count...

Comment: while, true, there is an assumption that is not called out in the description.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will do what you want:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(Grades)
  FROM (SELECT ID, Grade FROM Students WHERE ID = 3
        UNION
        VALUES (3, 0) -- Not certain of syntax here
       )
 GROUP BY ID
```

The basic idea is that students present in the table will have two rows and the MAX will pick their proper grade (assuming that there are no circumstances where the grade is coded as a negative value). Students that are not represented will have just the one row with a grade of 0.  The repeated 3 is the ID of the student being sought.

Have fun chasing down the full syntax.  I started at [Queries](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008467.html) in the DB2 9.7 Information Centre, but ran out of patience before I got a good answer — and I don't have DB2 to experiment on.  You might need to write `SELECT ID, Grades FROM VALUES (3, 0)`, or there might be some other magical incantation that does the job.  You could probably use `SELECT 3 AS ID, 0 AS Grades FROM SYSIBM.SYSTABLES WHERE TABID = 1`, but that's a clumsy expression.

I've kept with the column name `Grades` (plural) even though it looks like it contains one grade. It is depressing how often people ask questions about anonymous tables.

Comment: Well, the good news is that there's a table `sysdummy1` which contains only a single row, which is essentially used for a 'non-existant' row table.